# Unexpected quitting of the kernel when discretizing parametric region

Tags: regions, kernel

I have a region defined parametrically (-actually the union and difference of several ones), and when I try to discretize it Mathematica suddenly quits the kernel, as show in the picture below (I'm working with Mathematica 12.3.1.0 on MW 64-bit platform).

```
 f1[x_] := Piecewise[{{-x - 1.8, x < -1.8}, {0, -1.8 < x < -1}, {x + 1, -1 < x < 0}}]; 
 f2[x_] := Piecewise[{{x + 6.5, x < -3}, {-x + 0.5, x < -1}, {x + 2.5, -1 < x < 0}}]; 
 rf = ImplicitRegion[y <= 1.5*f1[x], {{x, -4.15, 0}, {y, 0, 5.5}}]; 
 rg = ImplicitRegion[y <= 1.5*f2[x], {{x, -4.15, 0}, {y, 0, 5.5}}]; 
 rf2 = ImplicitRegion[y <= 1.5*f1[-x], {{x, 0, 4.15}, {y, 0, 5.5}}]; 
 rg2 = ImplicitRegion[y <= 1.5*f2[-x], {{x, 0, 4.15}, {y, 0, 5.5}}]; 
 reg = RegionUnion[RegionDifference[rg, rf], RegionDifference[rg2, rf2]]; 
 ParametricPlot[{x, y}, Element[{x, y}, reg]] 

 DiscretizeRegion[reg]
```

[image]

Comment: The same happens with the newest version of MMA 13.1. Please report this to support@wolfram.com

Comment: code runs in Mathematica v12.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We `PiecewiseExpand` the expression of `reg`.

```
ImplicitRegion[PiecewiseExpand[reg[[1]]], {x, y}] // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image]